# Find M <= N such that sum of consequent numbers from 1 to x is M.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

I am given a number $N$. I need to find $M\le N$ such that $M$ can be written as a sum of consequent numbers from 1 to x.
 I know this formula $1+2+\cdots +n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.
How can I find such M?

Comment: Quadratic equation: $M^2+M=2N$

Comment: Thanks. Is there a ready formula that can find such M?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ 
\begin{align} 
&\, M \,=\, \sum_{k=1}^{n}k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \le N \\[2mm] 
&\, \frac{n(n+1)}{2}=N \,\Rightarrow\, n^2+n-2N=0 \,\Rightarrow\, n=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+8N}}{2} \\[2mm] 
&\, n\in{\mathbb N}^{+} \,\Rightarrow\, \color{red}{n=\left\lfloor \frac{\sqrt{8N+1}-1}{2} \right\rfloor} ,\,\, \color{blue}{M=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}
\end{align} 
$$

Comment: Do these brackets mean round down?

Comment: @BaimyrzaShamyr: Yes. See [Floor Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

Comment: Bravo! Simple and Impressive solution.